# How do I run two python functions simultaneously and stop others when any one them returns a value?

Tags: multithreading, async-await, python-multiprocessing

I want to write two python functions that request data from two different APIs (with similar data). Both the functions should start simultaneously and as soon as one of the functions (say fun1()) returns the result, the other function (say fun2()) is terminated and the rest of the program is carried out with the result obtained from fun1().

For example,

```
from datetime import datetime
def fun1(n): #Obtaining data from Source 1
        sums = -1
        if n > -1:
                sums = sum([x*x for x in range(n)])
        return sums

def fun2(n): #Obtaining data from source 2
        sums = -1
        if n > -1:
                sums = (n*(2*n+1)*(n+1))/6
        return int(sums)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        no = 999999
        print(fun1(no)) #Function Call 1
        print(fun2(no)) #Function Call 2
```

So I want to run both the functions `fun1()` and `fun2()` simultaneously so that as soon as one of them returns the value, the program stops the other function and prints the value from `fun1()`.

I tried to explore multiprocessing in python that offers parallel processing but in addition to that, I'm looking for some solution that stops other functions as soon as one of the functions returns some value.

***Note:** I'm using Python 3.10.6 on Ubuntu. The program above is just a dummy program to represent the problem.*

Comment: You show two functions that are CPU bound.  They do nothing but numerical calculations.  But in your description you say that the functions request data from somewhere, presumably a network.  That sounds like functions that are I/O bound.  The answer to your question is quite different in the two cases.  Are the functions are asyncio-aware?  Do they offer any methods to terminate them before they finish?  What harm would they do if you just let the slowest run to completion - would the user notice, or care?

Comment: @PaulCornelius I'm using python requests to get JSON data from two APIs. One of them is too slow (response time apx. 7-12 sec) while the faster one (response time apx. 3-6 sec) sometimes returns error. So I want to maximise success rate and minimise response time by waiting for the faster one to return result and if it shows error, the slower one continues as a backup.

Comment: You can't use multithreading because there is no graceful way to terminate a thread.  You can use asyncio but only if the request library supports it, otherwise not.  You can use multiprocessing but it's difficult and there is significant overhead.  How about trying the simple solution and just let the second request run to completion in the background, then ignoring the result?  Multithreading would work fine for that.  It wouldn't be the first time a computer did some unnecessary work that got thrown out.